# How to disable the lock screen on Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, lock-screen, lxde, lock

I want to disable the lock screen after suspend session of Lubuntu. But it seems Lubuntu doesn't have a lot of fans. Can anyone help me on this issue?

I don't want to lock the screen after suspension. Does anyone know **which file deals** this **locking in Lubuntu**?

Answer (score 14):

Go to Menu > Preferences > Power Manager > Security then uncheck box marked "Lock screen when system is going for sleep". You may have to log out and log back in for it to take effect.

Comment: I really wish there was some more convenient method, i.e. not having to log out and back in.  I like to turn off the lock screen for limited periods of time, and having to continually disrupt my desktop is kind of a deal breaker.

Comment: is this the standard procedure of Lubuntu? cause there is no security tab in Power Manager on LXQt

Comment: Lockscreen in Lubuntu 20.04 now appears to be located in Menu > Preferences > Screensaver. At the bottom of the "Display Modes" window there is a checkbox which from memory is disabled on a new install. It goes to a screensaver instead, which can be disabled at the top of window in the "Mode" box.

Answer (score 0):

Lock screen in Lubuntu 20.04.1 is in
Menu > Preferences > Power Manager > System tab, down to Security at the bottom; it is checked by default, just uncheck it.
Also in Menu > Preferences > ScreenSaver > Display Modes tab down at the bottom, make sure it's unchecked, as it's unchecked by default.